# How can I interpret a Test Plan in which I have set a "Ramp-up Period" greater than zero

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

This is the first time I had to perform tests and I'm kind of confused about how to interpret the results I got when setting "Ramp-up Period" greater than zero.

To start, when I set a value of zero, if I'm not mistaken, this means that all the threads are launched at the same time. Therefore, one can conclude that the max number of threads that your application can successfully accept is equivalent to the max number of **concurrent** requests the tested application can accept.

Now that problem comes when I have to do some tests using a "Ramp-up Period" greater that zero, as I'm not sure what conclusions can I come to, or rather I don't know whether they are correct.

Based on what the [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html) says:

> Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as
>   needed.

This is more or less what I've written:

1) To start our test we set that each thread will start 1 (15/15)  second after the previous thread was begun. To do this we set the same value for both “Number of threads” and “Ramp-up Period”.

[image]

[image]

As the 15 requests are done successfully we start adjusting down the value for "Ramp-up Period", until we find the minimum interval of time that must exist between each request

2) Ramp-up Period = 13

3) Ramp-up Period = 10

4) Ramp-up Period = 7

5) Ramp-up Period = 6

So far all the requests were performed successfully, but with a "Ramp-up Period" of 6 only three requests had a response.

[image]

### With this result we can conclude that the minimum time that must elapse between each call to the web service must be greater or equal to 0.46 seconds

### This value is calculated by dividing the value of "Number of threads" and "Ramp-up (7 / 15)

What do you think about my conclusion? Is it right? What else one can conclude using jmeter in the way I showed.

As always your comments suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ramp up is nothing more than virtual users arrival rate. JMeter starts from 1 thread and adds more threads as per ramp-up specified. 15 threads and 15 seconds ramp-up means that each 1 second 1 thread is being added. In case of 7 seconds ramp-up and 15 threads each second 2 threads are added. When thread doesn't have any work to do it's being shut down so make sure that you have enough loops in the parent Thread Group or Loop Controller.

There are at least 3 options of defining load scenario:

1. [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) (free 3rd-party plugin) - provides convenient way of setting ramp-up, ramp-down and hold the load times.
2. [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) - provides capability to set the load in "requests per minute"
3. [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) - provides the way of pausing requests until specified thread number is reached and firing them off at the same moment creating simultaneous concurrent requests.

Also:

- Please don't use JMeter GUI for anything apart from tests development and debugging
- Avoid View Results in Table Listener
- The same for View Results Tree listener.
- Follow other advices from [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T , but tell me do you think my conclusions are OK?

Comment: I don't think that it's a good way to determine server's maximum load rate as depending on actual concurrent active threads number behavior may vary. I would rather go for well known load like "10 requests/second", "20 requests/second", etc. and mention when errors are observed. From that moment you can profile application, add telemetry, extra logging, monitor server health, etc. to get to the bottom of errors cause.

Comment: In order to have a certain number of requests/second , I will have to specify the same value for both the "Number of Threads" and "Ramp-up Period", is that right??

Comment: To have certain number of requests/second you need to use Constant Throughput Timer.